# PHP header no me redirecciona

Tags: php

estoy enviando un email con un botón para confirmar el registro de usuario. Al pulsar el botón se va a la web y llama a un fichero php que actualiza en la base de datos el estado del usuario a Activo y pretendo recargar la página enviando un parámetro ok si ha ido bien o un error. El caso es que el header no me va y me gustaría saber por qué. Os dejo el código:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_GET['key'],$_SESSION['app_id'])){
  require('class.Conexion.php');
  session_start();
  $db = new Conexion();
  $id = (int)$_SESSION['app_id'];
  $key = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['key']);
  $db->query("UPDATE USERS SET activo=1, temp_pwd='' WHERE id=$id;"); 
 --> ACTUALIZA CORRECTAMENTE
  $db->liberar($sql);
  $db->close();
  //header('location: ?view=index&success=true'); --> NO FUNCIONA
  //header('Location: https://miweb.com?success=true'); --> NO FUNCIONA
  //header('Location: index.php?success=true'); --> NO FUNCIONA

 echo "<script>location.href = 'https://miweb.com?success=true'; 
      </script>"; --> SI FUNCIONA

 }else{
    $db->liberar($sql);
    $db->close();
    header('location: ?view=index&error=true');
 }
}else{
    header('location:index.php');
}
 ?>
```

Comment: tal vez deberia ver este articulo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: ¿Cuál de los `header` es el que no va? Te recomendaría que en vez de liarte con tantas redirecciones, uses Ajax para esto, podrías hacer cualquier cosa sin tener que moverte de la página.

Comment: Quiero recargar la página para que no se vea el parámetro Key que envío desde el link del email después de haber actualizado el estado del usuario. Me recarga la página sólo con echo "<script>...". Voy a echarle un vistazo al artículo que me ha enviado Jose. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué no optas mejor por Ajax? Te aseguro que no te vas a arrepentir y cuando aprendas a usarlo (se aprende en un día, es muy simple) entrarás en una nueva dimensión de la programación cliente-servidor y te olvidarás tener que estar recargando páginas. O sea, con Ajax puedes hacer una comunicación entre cliente y servidor llevando y trayendo datos, ejecutando acciones, etc y mostrar en el cliente lo que haga falta. Y crearás un programa más amigable, pues es más elegante actualizar la página sin recargarla.

Comment: `$db->liberar($sql);` y  `$db->close();` están haciendo un output y por eso no está permitiendo que el `header` funcione, además de que la palabra `location` debe de ser `Location` con L mayúscula.